# how to hide the complete path in php with htacces file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a project with the name of social app which contains has a structure like this:

- includes

  - _login.php
  - _profile.php
- pages

  - login.php
  - profile.php

currently if I want to vists any page like profile.php I have to visit **localhost/social-app/pages/login.php** but I want to modify it and change the url to **localhost/social-app/login.php**. basically I want to get rid of the pages and make my URL a bit cleaner

Comment: You want a Virtual Host defined for your site - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/

Answer (score 3):

In your `htaccess` in the root , put the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^social-app/login\.php$ /social-app/pages/login.php [L]
```

Now instead of going to long URL you can just type `/social-app/login.php` to access the file in `pages` folder.

EDIT :

To remove the directory name for all files , you can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/social-app/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^social-app/([^.]+)\.php$ /social-app/pages/$1.php [L]
```

If the rule above fails , then use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^social-app/(.+)\.php$ /social-app/pages/$1.php [L]
```

This will internally map a request for `/social-app/filename.php` to `/social-app/pages/filename.php` .

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I want to do the same thing for each and every page not just login. do you know how can  I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If *everything* (ie. images, CSS, JS and PHP pages) need to be rewritten to the `/pages` subdirectory then you can do something like the following in the `/social-app/.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^pages/ pages%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This unconditionally rewrites everything that is not already prefixed with `pages/` to the `pages` subdirectory. eg. `/social-app/login.php` is internally rewritten to `/social-app/pages/login.php`.

If you have static resources in other locations that should not be rewritten then include a filesystem check to prevent requests that already map to existing files from being rewritten. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^pages/ pages%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

If you are changing an existing URL structure then you'll need to redirect the old URLs that are indexed by search engines and perhaps linked to from third parties. For example, the following "redirect" would need to go *before* the above rewrite:

```
RewriteBase /social-app

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) $1 [R=301,L]
```